# How can I detect what causes Chrome to open a tab for "http://eaes.2track.info/" each time I search something in the address bar?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, malware, malware-detection

How can I detect what causes Chrome to open a tab for "http://eaes.2track.info/" each time I search something in the address bar?

Interestingly this only happens for the first few searches I do after starting the Windows. Afterward it doesn't open a tab for "http://eaes.2track.info/" anymore.

---

Some details:

- I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.
- I don't see anything suspicious in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features`. Only Chrome is affected: Internet Explorer and Firefox are fine. Chrome with incognito mode is also working fine.
- Avast isn't complaining about anything
- Looking at chrome://settings/searchEngines, the address bar uses Google with `{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}`, which seems fine to me.
  [image]
- I have noticed a few bookmark icons changing to [image] (WM is expected, but the icon before it changed).
- Running chrome://settings/safetyCheck doesn't show any issue with the extensions.
- `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` just contains one line of `NUL` characters (probably got nuked by some non-malicious crapware some time ago).
- I have the extension "Auto Refresh" (ID=`ifooldnmmcmlbdennkpdnlnbgbmfalko`) but it isn't loaded. I assume this means it doesn't run.

  [image]

Comment: Please see this link for information about "eaes.2track.info" at __symantec.com__ https://safeweb.symantec.com/report/show?url=eaes.2track.info You can also run another queary yourself, for other sites too. Of course, the real judge is you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same thing happened to me, apparently the extension "Auto Refresh" is malware.

Comment: Thanks, interesting, I do have  extension "Auto Refresh"  but it isn't loaded. I had assumed this means it doesn't run. Let me try to remove it to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Looks like this fixed the issue. I'll wait a few days before accepting to check if the issue is gone for good

Comment: Follow-up question:  [Does disabling a Google Chrome extension prevent any code of the extension from being executed?](https://superuser.com/q/1559709/116475)

Comment: For Chrome extensions, Disabling isn't the same as removing... I don't know why this is the case because it should be....

Comment: same happened to me  and in office :(

Answer (score 3):

malicious code is in its background.js
You can read about it in this reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/gg2nii/auto_refresh_extension_now_malware/fql6uds/

Also these guys have create multiple other extensions for chrome and ff. example: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-refresh/hmooaemjmediafeacjplpbpenjnpcneg

Be careful while installing extensions.

Comment: Thanks. Does Chrome runs `background.js` even when the extension is disabled?

Comment: no. it runs only when enabled

Comment: Was there research done about the extent of the damage for this extension? Was it just a deliverer or was it a keylogger too?