# Does disabling a Google Chrome extension prevent any code of the extension from being executed?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I disabled a Google Chrome extension:

[image]

However, based on [some recent experience](https://superuser.com/q/1559657/116475), I am starting to wonder whether disabling a Google Chrome extension is a guarantee that no code from the extension is executed.

Does disabling a Google Chrome extension prevent any code of the extension from being executed?

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate if that matters, with the latest Google Chrome version (Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

Comment: If it is a malicious extension it may be able to do just that, bypass chromes built in protections.

Answer (score -1):

Since it a malware it may able to bypass settings like pc malwares bypass settings
Malwares are intended to bypass restrictions and cause damage in any device

In official google chrome extensions in chrome web store they are mostly unable to since they are checked & verified check before published not to violate any rules

Always install chrome extensions from Chrome webstore